# automatically changing the regular expression in awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Im new to awk and coding in general.
I have a database.txt file containing a number of gene sequences (300000+). The contain the gene name, followed by its protein sequence. e.g

```
gi|68687686|
MTHBOBJKDBKDBKDNJDN
```

I have a list of 100 gene names in a separate file (search.txt) and which to use awk to select the gene names, and the protein sequence below the gene name for each of my one 100 genes.

I can use a 'print between two regex' in awk by adding a regex 'ABC123' before every gene and using

```
awk'/\>gi\|678676868\|/,/ABC123/' database.txt
```

This works fine, however, this only allows me to search for a single gene at a time. I would like to  automate this process for my 100 gene names in the search.txt file. is there a way I can pipe the 100 gene names form the search.txt file into the first regular expression above? I.e switch out and switch in the gene names automatically?

Comment: Provide enough sample data and expected output to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your search file has the entirety of the `gi|########|` lines as its line content and assuming you want to print everything between the matching `gi|########|` line and the next `gi|########|` line. I believe the following will do what you want.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    s[$0]++
    next
}

/^gi\|/ {
    p=0
    if (s[$0]) {
        p=1
    }
}

p' search.txt database.txt
```

If your search file only has the numerical bit between the pipes in it then the `FNR==NR` loop needs to be changed to use `s["gi|"$0"|"]++` instead and that should still work.